# maven mac app bundle plugin can't find custom Info.plist

Tags: java, macos, maven

I'm using the maven os x application bundle plugin so that I can create a mac-executable version of a java launcher. I have to do this as part of two steps to not give my users Gatekeeper trouble...

I'm having to configure a custom plist to properly set the java working directory (code runs fine when you click the jar, crashes with exit code 1 when you click the .app)

The plugin allows you to make your own plist and indicate where it's at in the pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>osxappbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.helion3.Launcher</mainClass>
        <dictionaryFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/Info.plist</dictionaryFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

The file exists at that location. When I run `mvn package`, it now fails:

`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:osxappbundle-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1:bundle (default) on project liftoff: Could not find resource for template /Users/myacct/Documents/workspace/MyProgram/src/main/resources/Info.plist`

When I run `vi /Users/myacct/Documents/workspace/MyProgram/src/main/resources/Info.plist`, the file opens properly.

My plist itself should be valid because I copied the one that was originally generated, added a single workingDirectory key, and replaced some values with the plugin's placeholders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="0.9">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${bundleName}</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>${describe}</string>
    <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
    <string>true</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>JavaApplicationStub</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>GenericJavaApp.icns</string>
    <key>Java</key>
    <dict>
      <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
      <string>$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/Resources</string>
      <key>MainClass</key>
      <string>${mainClass}</string>
      <key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.4+</string>
      <key>ClassPath</key>
      ${classpath}
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone will come here from search engines, here is my solution.

Switch to the latest version of the plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>osxappbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    ....
</plugin>
```

I used alpha-1 and got the same errors.